Define two routes with same base on Symfony
I have two routes GET /users/{id} and POST /users/{id}/file.
When I try to call the second one (POST /users/{id}/file), I get an error 405 Method Not Allowed.
I use Symfony 6.4.
My routes are defined with attributes:
# Get.php
#[Route('/users/{id}', name: 'get_user', methods: ['GET'], requirements: ['id' => '.+'])]

# AddFile.php
#[Route('/users/{id}/file', name: 'add_user_file', methods: ['POST'], requirements: ['id' => '.+'])]

My config/routes.yaml file:
home:
  path: /
  controller: App\Controller\HomeController

controllers:
  resource:
    path: ../src/Controller/
    namespace: App\Controller
  type: attribute
  prefix: /
  exclude:

When I use the debug:router command, I see properly my two routes.



Name
Method
Scheme
Host
Path




get_user
GET
Any
Any
/users/{id}


add_user_file
POST
Any
Any
/users/{id}/file



Do you have any idea of what I'm missing?

Hi, could you please share your routes configuration file (config/routes.yml) and a simplified version of your controller class. Symfony supports service & controller auto detection, maybe there is some configuration issue?

Hi, I just update my original post to add my conf file. The controllers don't have any logic, just a dump('here');die; to test...
Reading my original post : as the ID can be any character (look at the requirements for the ID parameter), do you think the GET request intercepts the POST ?

Referring to the id parameter thing, you're probably right, to test just change the order of these two methods/actions :D I was on the wrong track

The routes are ambiguous, since POST /users/{id}/file will be matched by BOTH route paths.
The first route Symfony sees is the one that's going to match, and since it can't handle POST, you get an error.
You cannot simply decide which is loaded first for attribute defined routes, so you need to use the priority parameter.
For example:
# Get.php
#[Route('/users/{id}',
      name: 'get_user',
      methods: ['GET'],
      requirements: ['id' => '.+'])]

# AddFile.php
#[Route('/users/{id}/file',
         name: 'add_user_file', 
         methods: ['POST'], 
         requirements: ['id' => '.+'], 
         priority: 1)]

With this, since add_user_file has higher priority than get_user, it will be checked first.

Another option that should work is to be a bit more specific in your requirements property RegExp:
#[Route('/users/{id}', name: 'get_user', methods: ['GET'], requirements: ['id' => '[^/]+'])]

#[Route('/users/{id}/file', name: 'add_user_file', methods: ['POST'], requirements: ['id' => '[^/]+'])]

The above will match one or more of any character that's not a forward slash "/".
But that is still somewhat ambiguous, try more closely matching the actual pattern of your id field
'\d+' - one or more digits 0-9)
'\w{16}' - "\w" matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) "{16}" matches the previous token exactly 16 times
This way you don't have to keep track of the priority property across multiple controller files.

Finally, I found a solution: as the ID cannot contain a /, I simply updated the regex.
For the record, playing with priorities didn't work (the first GET route was always called first).
Thanks to all of you.
